# Save data of django form in database

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm using Django 1.3 and I have a form defined with forms.py:

```
class mopa(forms.Form):
    idcarrellosorgente = forms.IntegerField(label="Identificativo Carrello Sorgente *", required=True, max_value=9999999999, min_value=0000000000 )
    causale = forms.CharField(label="Causale Pagamento *", required=True)
    imp_unitario = forms.DecimalField(label="Importo Unitario Bene (es. 20.00) *", required=True)
    quantita_item = forms.IntegerField(label="Quantita' Bene Acquistato (intero) *", required=True)
```

and in this file I made the checks.
My models.py file:

```
class Mopamodel(models.Model):
    idcarrellosorgente = models.IntegerField()
    cod_ente = models.CharField()
    causale = models.CharField()
    imp_unitario = models.DecimalField()
    quantita_item = models.IntegerField()
```

and my views.py

```
def paga(request):

    # If this is a POST request then process the Form data
     if request.method == 'POST':

    #  Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request (binding):
    form = mopa(request.POST)
    print('form: ', form.data) #return a dictionary

    # Check if the form is valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required 
        # p=form.save() <--don't works: error: 'mopa' object has no attribute 'save'
        idcarr = form.cleaned_data['idcarrellosorgente']         
        caus = form.cleaned_data['causale']
        imp_u = form.cleaned_data['imp_unitario']
        qta = form.cleaned_data['quantita_item']

        dictmopa={}
        dictmopa['id_carr']=idcarr
        cod_ente = form.cleaned_data['cod_ente']
        mopapay=Mopamodel(idcarrellosorgente=idcarr, cod_ente=cod_ente, causale=causale, imp_unitario=imp_u, quantita_item=qta
        #mopapay.save() <--this produce the error: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Decimal' and 'NoneType'
        ....
        # redirect to a new URL:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('viewsdati/') )
```

How can I save the form data in a database postgres? 
Other tutorial/questions don't solve my problem, probably are for more recent django versions.

Comment: ok check for modelforms in django and make sure you use latest versions it have more features

Comment: try form.save()

Comment: @Vicmathur the OP is not using a `ModelForm`.

Comment: ModelForms are available at least since Django 1.0, and that's what they are for. But you should __really__ upgrade to a supported Django version.

Comment: I use form.save but I receive the error: 'mopa' object has no attribute 'save'

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should use `ModelForm` in this case. Change forms like this:

```
class mopa(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Mopamodel
         fields = ('idcarrellosorgente ', 'causale', 'imp_unitario', 'quantita_item ', )
```

Then change view to something like this:

```
def paga(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = mopa(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           posted = form.save(commit=False)
           posted.cod_ente = form.cleaned_data['cod_ente']
           posted.save()

           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('viewsdati/'))
```

Comment: I don't see the reason why you didn't include field `cod_ente` in the forms, maybe you have a good reason, but if it is a mistake, then include that field in the forms and save the form directly with `form.save()`.